# C++ auto deduce type of template member pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

I have this code:

```cpp
struct Test {
    std::string s;
};

template <typename T,
         auto T::* groupPtr>    
         struct Base{
             using BaseType = typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>().*groupPtr)>::type;

             void Process(const Test * e){
                 printf("%s\n", e->s.c_str());

                 BaseType tmp = e->*groupPtr;       
                 printf("%s\n", tmp.c_str());
             }
         };

int main(){
    Test t;
    t.s = "x";

    Base<Test, &Test::s> r;
    r.Process(&t);
}
```

However, compilation ends with an error:

```
main.cpp: error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from
'std::string Test::* ' to 'auto Test::* '

main.cpp: message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion
requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

main.cpp: error C3535: cannot deduce type for 'auto Test::* ' from
'int'

main.cpp: message : see reference to class template instantiation
'Base<Test,0>' being compiled
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with C++17 enabled.

Why is construction cannot be auto-deduced? Or is it even possible?

Comment: `&Test::s` is not a type

Comment: What about `auto groupPtr` instead of `auto T::* groupPtr` ?

Comment: Another interesting element: your code compile with clang++ but gives an error ("error: unable to deduce 'auto T::*' from '&Test::s'") with g++. I've added the "language-lawyer" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems c++ forgot to include auto deduction for member pointers in TMP. I have tried with c++20 and failed. This is a big issue. But we can have a workaround for the same as in the following.

Consindering your code should work but doesn't due to 'c++ limitations'. We will only modify a bit of it. Do as follows.

```cpp
struct Test {
    std::string s;
};
template <typename T,typename BaseType,
        BaseType (T::*groupPtr)>
struct Base{
    void Process(const Test * e){
        printf("%s\n", e->s.c_str());

        BaseType tmp = e->*groupPtr;
        printf("%s\n", tmp.c_str());
    }
};

int main(){
    Test t;
    t.s = "x";
    static constexpr auto (Test::*s)=&Test::s;
    Base<Test,std::decay<decltype(std::declval<Test>().*s)>::type, s> r;
    r.Process(&t);
}
```

The above coding finally works.

Comment: I have cretaed "one" liner version (usefull for using or some macro etc) - `Base<Test, std::decay<decltype(Test::s)>::type, &Test::s>`

Answer (score 2):

Clang is correct that this code is valid: `auto` can be used as a *decl-specifier* for any kind of declaration of a function, variable, or template parameter.  You can’t, on the other hand, use it in other places in the declaration:

```
int auto::*f() {…}      // not in a ptr-operator
std::vector<auto> x=…;  // not in a template argument
```

Answer (score -3):

Your template needs more info than that to do what you want.  It is also very difficult, if not impossible to do what you want without using 'questionable' (one should avoid using reinterptret_cast<>) pointer gymnatics.  And using macros will give us some syntactic sugar.

This example uses references for ease of use, modifying to use (or add suuport for) pointers should be easy enough.

```
#include <cstddef>   // offsetof()
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <string>

template <typename _ClassT, typename _MemberT, size_t _Offset>
struct Base {
  void Process(const _ClassT& e) {
    std::cout << GetMemberRef(e);  // your code used printf(), but you shouldn't
                                   // assume the type of the inner member.
                                   // That's the whole point of this exercise,
                                   // isn't it?
    auto& tmp = GetMemberRef(e);
    std::cout << tmp;
  }

  // the name of access functions is quite verbose, but that's for 
  // demonstration purposes only.

  static const _MemberT& GetMemberRef(const _ClassT& e) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const _MemberT*>(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e) + _Offset);
  }

  static _MemberT& GetMemberRef(_ClassT& e) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<_MemberT*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e) + _Offset);
  }
};

// utility to make instantiation a bit easier to read and write...
// I don't think there is a way to do that without a macro.
#define MakeBase(type, member) \
  Base<type, decltype(type::member), offsetof(type, member)> {}

// test the code...

struct Test {
  std::string s;
};

struct Test2 {
  int value = 42;
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.s = "x";

  // declaration is a bit awkward, but there are no ways around that.      
  Base<Test, decltype(Test::s), offsetof(Test, s)> r;
  r.Process(t);

  // using MakeBase utility macro is quite clean, though. 
  auto x = MakeBase(Test2, value);
  x.Process(Test2{});
}
```

Comment: My solution works, the only problem is with `auto`. If I put correct type istead of `auto`, all is working. With `auto`, it works in clang.

Comment: Your explanation is not correct. While the language rules may not allow `auto` in that context, the necessary information to deduce it is available.

Comment: @MartinPerry  Your solution does not compile, does it?  It's because the language does not allow the use of auto in template parameters.   "member of a class"  is not a type either, it is only a type qualifier.

Comment: @cigien  Deducing the type, yes, but not its offset from the object base address.  There is no mechanism to pass the name of a member variable in c++17.  c++20 introspection brings the possibility to do that.  offsetof() is actually a macro.  it reads somthing like this: `#define offetof(type, member) (size_t) (&reinterpret_cast<type*>(nullptr)->member)` .